# Does strict transport security survive across restarts?

Tags: https

The TorBrowser will honor HSTS settings during a session, meaning that if you visit an HTTPS site and the HSTS flag is set, the browser will not allow an HTTP downgrade.  Does this survive across restarts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://projects.dm.id.lv/Public-Key-Pins_test) test site, HSTS information does not survive a reboot on TBB 4.5 nor TBB 5 Alpha supported.  This is *probably* because HSTS can be used to track browsers.  It sounds as if the [preload list](http://tsyrklevich.net/2014/10/28/abusing-strict-transport-security/) will be supported and should protect users of major websites that enable HSTS.

Comment: Note the preload list has certain caveats, so not *all* HSTS sites will be included.

Comment: @AndrewLott Have any useful links?  I would love to link to the policy if it is laid out somewhere....

Comment: https://hstspreload.appspot.com details the requirements.